# Live tile sometimes doesn't show local generated image, but does when its re-pinned?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I'm having a strange problem. I generate my live tile images in the BackgroundTask based on weather information. Sometimes I see that the image is being generated, but the tile only shows its background color and not the image (for instance, the tile is green or red and it shows only the title).

When I then remove the live tile, and re-pin it to the start screen the image does show. Or, on Windows Phone 8, when I change the size (Small => Medium => Wide) the live tile shows the image just fine. It sometimes happens on the Background image, and on the BackBackground image. Even re-starting the phone  or open the app seems to help (but not 100% on this).

This seems like a small bug in the Windows Phone OS. What could be the problem?

This is my code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/Image.jpg",     System.IO.FileMode.Create, ISF))
    {
        writeableTileFinal.SaveJpeg(imageStream, writeableTileFinal.PixelWidth, writeableTileFinal.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    }
}



ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
if (appTile != null)
{
    StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData()
    {
        Title = "Title",
        BackContent = string.Empty,
        BackTitle = string.Empty,
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/Image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),

    };
    appTile.Update(tileData);
}
```

[image: Image that shows what I mean:]

**UPDATE:**

I seem to have fixed it (it didn't happen afterwards) by using Thread.Sleep just before the tile updates itself.:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);

appTile.Update(tileData);
```

It works, but does someone knows what could have been the problem?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it (it didn't happen afterwards) by using Thread.Sleep just before the tile updates itself.:

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    appTile.Update(tileData);

It works, but does someone knows what could have been the problem?

Kind regards,

Niels